# How can I use OSHI to get a file's HWDiskStore？

Tags: oshi

Recently I was required to use OSHI to monitor hardware, a request is to get a file's HWDiskStore, I searched OSHI's api for a while, and didn't find a specific method just like `FileStore getFileStore(Path path)` to achieve the request, I already known that Sigar could get a file's mountpoint such like `sigar.getFileSystemMap().getMountPoint(pathName).getDirName()`, so I wonder that if OSHI has similar method to get file's mountpoint. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, that really can solve my problem, thank you very much~ By the way, do you know some introduction document about OSHI? all I know now is a github project https://github.com/oshi/oshi/, but that is not enough at all, do you know any other OSHI document which could offer more demostration about it's API? Thank a lot~

Comment: I'm the primary author of OSHI.  For usage demonstration there are two places to look, one is the SystemInfoTest file (linked from the README).   The other is the source code in the oshi-demo artifact.   I'll go ahead and add a demo file for matching up disk store/partition and filestore given a file.

Comment: I just wrote a quick [demo class](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/master/oshi-demo/src/main/java/oshi/demo/DiskStoreForPath.java) showing how to do it.

Comment: That demo is really helpful, thank a lot~ and... I just noticed that you're the primary author of that project https://github.com/oshi/oshi, that's really coincidental and I really feel a little lucky. My boss recently recommended me to learn this project to know more about OSHI, will your team keep updating that project?

Comment: By "team" it's mostly me, but yes I plan to keep maintaining the project.

Comment: That's such a hard work for you, and I'll keep following the updates.